# How to retrieve altitude from pixel value in a PNG file requested from GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, unity3d

I'm using a GeoServer 2.18 from Unity for terrain rendering. I'm asking the GeoServer this kind request:

```
{0,1}wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=Elevation&bbox={3,1},{4,1},{5,1},{6,1}&width={2,1}&height={1,1}&srs=EPSG:900913&format=image/png
```

on elevation data. I've got a nice black and white PNG file but how can I convert the pixel value into a real altitude?

Answer (score 1):

A WMS returns a PNG that's a 8bit rendered image, with some color palette, either provided by you, or automatically determined by the server. The result should not be used to determine elevation, but just to provide a visual look at it.

If you want to get the elevation of a particular point either:

- Use a [GetFeatureInfo request](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getfeatureinfo)
- Try out the *unsupported* [DDS/BIL output format](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/dds/index.html), picking a nightly build for it matching the GeoServer version you're using (community modules do not have release packages, only nightly builds).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as I mentioned I would like to decode the pixel value, how do I know how the palette is set (how does the range is determined). I don't want to get the altitude for a particular point.

Comment: If you associated an SLD with a color map, it's the one you specified there, otherwise it's dynamically determined so that the highest value in the rendered area is matched to 255, and the lowest to 0.

Comment: Ok, thank you, the colormap is set from the Geoserver webpage ? Sorry, I'm a beginner with geoserver. It's not at request time setting  because i saw an elevation parameter in the WMS that can may be do the job.
elevation=rangemin:rangemax.